# Avoid hard coding in mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, oop, database-schema

I have a table of ban reasons:

```
id | short_name | description
 1      virus     Virus detected in file
 2      spam      Spammy file
 3      illegal   Illegal content
```

When I ban a file for being a virus, in my code I do this:

```
$file -> banVirus();
```

Which inserts the file id and ban reason into a table:

```
"INSERT INTO 'banned_files' VALUES (61234, 1)"
```

My question is; **is it a problem that I have hard-coded the value 1?**, to indicate a spam file.

Should I use defines in my config like define ('SPAM', 1), so i can replace 1 with a define? Or does it not matter at all?

Comment: Why don't you just make it an optional parameter?

Comment: If you maintained the code, what would you like to see in the source, `SPAM` or `1`?

Comment: Looks fine to me as you've only got 3 ban types, they're very easy to remember. If you had 50+ of them I might think differently.

Comment: not really a problem, but you might want to put in a comment saying that this `1` corresponds to an entry in your "ban reasons" table, so later maintainers know where to look... and since you're wrapping the insert in a function with a pretty descriptive name, that helps a lot too

Comment: Instead of using an auto-incremented primary key for the ban reason id ... you could just use the `short_name` that keeps your database relational and normalised and gives you a descriptive ban reason when used elsewhere (in the application for example).

Comment: The fact that the method is called banVirus() should be enough. However if you used banFile() then I would say use a define or something.

Comment: It is not problem, but your readability could be improved with your idea.  Depending on the scope of this value, you could also define a constant within your $file class (SPAM) for 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the `id` is an *auto incrementing* field, then it is a *very big problem*! Since the ids are automatically generated, it's hard to guarantee their stability; i.e. they may change.

If the `id` is something you manually assigned, it's not such a big problem, but it's bad practice. Because magic numbers easily lead to confusion and mistakes. Who knows what "`1`" means when reading your code?

So either way, you'd be better off to assign a *stable, readable* id to each case.

I agree with @Tenner that it also hardly makes sense to have a table for this static, unchanging data to begin with. Your `banned_files` table should have a column like this:

```
reason ENUM('virus', 'spam', 'illegal') NOT NULL
```

You need nothing more in your database. When outputting this for the user, you can add a readable reason with a simple array through your PHP code.

Comment: I disagree with your first statement.  While it could be an autoincrementing field, it is in a "lookup" table.  There is another table, banned_files that has a foreign key to the banned reason files.

Comment: So? But the `1` is hardcoded in PHP while the id may change in the database. That's an unstable relationship, hence a problem.

Comment: That seems a better solution for inserting. If possible, could you provide a simple example of how to add a readable reason using an array?

Comment: @paul `$reasons = array('virus' => 'The file is a virus.', ...); echo $reasons[$row['reason']];`

Comment: How or why do you think the the `1` would change in the ban_reasons table?  I can't imagine a scenario where a programmer changes table records for no apparent reason.  I am not arguing that it could be changed, but you have to make assumptions of what others will do with access to your database.  If the argument is that within PHP they are using a value of 1 and not a constant, then agreed - It should not be hardcoded.  I just disagree that the stability of the values of the ban_reasons table is a concern.

Comment: @deceze thanks, but doesn't that cause another "unstable relationship", between the enum value and the key in the array?

Comment: @AgRizzo For whatever reason you setup the database tables while the autoincrement value is not set to `1`. The records will receive some random id. Just the pure fact that you're relying on auto-generated ids where there's a possibility that they may not be generated exactly the same way every time is bad.

Comment: @paul *You* decide those values, you have full control over them. You do not have perfect control over auto-incremented values. You'll also insert those values into the database *from* PHP, e.g.: `INSERT INTO banned_files (..., reason) VALUES (..., 'virus')`, so they're now hardcoded *only* in PHP. The column definition in the database is only a restriction which values the column accepts; yes, you'll need to keep that in sync with your code.

Comment: Well, we will have to agree to disagree.  I stand by my initial argument - I don't think the ID's in the dictionary/ lookup table are hard to guarantee stability, especially when I quote you 3 paragraphs down 'it also hardly makes sense to have a table for this static, unchanging data'.  I do appreciate an insight from another's perspective and will probably write better code now.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have a fixed (and small) number of parameters, I'd be tempted to make the IDs an enum in your code and not even include them as a separate database table at all.

Think about something like gender -- which has two (or more) options, both fixed. (We won't be adding multiple new genders anytime soon.) I guarantee most registration systems' don't have a GENDER table with two entries in it.

So, table `banned_files` would be something like this:

```
id      | reason
--------+------------
12345   | 1
67890   | 2
```

and your code would contain enums as necessary:

```
enum BanReason {
    Virus = 1,
    Spam = 2,
    Illegal = 3
}
```

(please convert to PHP; I'm a C# developer!)

In PHP:

```
$aBanReason = array(
    'Virus' => 1,
    'Spam' => 2,
    'Illegal' => 3
);
```

Comment: Since the id is used at the database level as a value of a column it is not good practice to have it described in some random code with enumerations. It couples the two, it is certainly not clear if required to look it up in the future. Having a dictionary table is a common good practice, unless the value is binary like GENDER as you mentioned where a TINYINT in MySQL will suffice and the column name describes itself.